# How to use datepicker in yii2 basic?

Tags: yii2

I want to use yii2 datepicker but I'm having trouble to implement this. It does not show the date picker and I don't know what is missing in my code. I'm still new in this yii

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">

<div class="myproj-index">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['layout' => 'horizontal']); ?>
        <? //$form->field($model, 'periodfrom')
           echo DatePicker::widget([
               'model' => $model,
               'attribute' => 'periodfrom',
               'language' => 'en',
               'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
           ]);
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I downloaded this file here [jui](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui)

I found out that in my file I have no jui folder under yiisoft folder. My question in appasset how can I declare this files ?

**Answer**

I fixed it, I downloaded the jquery-ui files then added them to the bower folder in yii2.

Comment: To render with proper labels use <?php echo $form->field($model, 'date_created')->widget(DatePicker::className(),['clientOptions' => ['periodfrom' => '1980-01-01'],'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd']) ?>

Comment: Just curious, how to load the datepicker inline?

Answer (score 18):

First install this extension through composer.

1. run: `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui "*"` in your project directory.
2. update composer.
3. In your view file use `use yii\jui\DatePicker;`.

You probably did not install Datepicker in the vendor package.
Thanks.

Comment: One more thing: when using `composer`, make sure you are **inside basic directory** ( if you have any ), otherwise you will install it in the wrong palce.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `use .....\DatePicker;` ?

Also are you including the jui asset and everything, take a look at the source, do you have jui and all the JS included?

**Edit:**
Have you done a "composer update" lately?

Comment: I donwloaded the file here http://jqueryui.com/ ,and put the css and js,under web directory,also i add it to appasset.php,but I get this error Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found

Comment: you did not install yii2 properly I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code if you are using kartik datetime picker

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(),['options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter event time ...'],'pluginOptions' => [....]]) ?>
```